# How to run Cucumber Selenium Maven with Junit project in Parallel

Tags: maven, selenium, cucumber-junit

Iam using Selenium Cucumber Maven framework with Junit. How can we run cucumber feature files in parallel from Command line. I am very thankful if you guys help me. Please help me with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this article https://automationrhapsody.com/running-cucumber-tests-in-parallel/

First of all you need to write (or generate) runner classes for each feature file. Next configure the maven-surefire-plugin to run tests in parallel. If you are using maven-failsafe-plugin look at https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html for the configuration.

Be careful in which setup you run the tests. I would recommend you to setup a selenium grid with one master and multiple slaves to avoid hardware restrictions and of course concurrency issues.

Comment: Thnks for the reply patrick. Let me try this and update you the progress

Comment: I have added cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin and maven-surefire-plugin as mentioned. Getting Build success in command line. But one of the feature file is being executed .Can you please help

Comment: One or none of the feature files is being executed?
Do you have generated Runner classes per feature file in any directory?
Have a look at the sources of the article https://github.com/llatinov/selenium-samples-java/tree/master/cucumber-parallel - first of all try to get this example sources run and then you can look up for differences in your project

Comment: I have only one feature file and it is not executing . But getting Build success

Comment: Run mvn clean test from command line. Look in target/generated-test-sources/cucumber, is there a file called Parallel01IT.java? If yes then the cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin worked fine. In addition show me your pom.xml (at least the maven-surefire-plugin part)

Comment: <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19</version>
    <configuration>
        <forkCount>10</forkCount>
        <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
        <includes>
            <include>**/Parallel*IT.class</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

Comment: <plugin><groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId><artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId><version>1.0.1</version><executions><execution><id>generateRunners</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
                  <configuration>
                <glue>stepDefinition</glue>
                <featuresDirectory>src/test/resources</featuresDirectory>
                <cucumberOutputDir>target/cucumber-parallel</cucumberOutputDir>
                <format>json,html</format>
                <tags>"~@ignored"</tags>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>

Comment: what's about the Parallel01IT.java file at the target directory? Did the cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin work?

Comment: In target/generated-test-sources/cucumber, instead of the file called Parallel01IT.java, another empty folder named test-annotations is created. can you please correct me?

Comment: i see the problem. you need to add the goal generateRunners to the cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin. I would recommend you to check out the example code from the github repo (link above) and compare your version with the sample version. 
the following part is missing in your cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin configuration:
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generateRunners</goal>
                        </goals>

Comment: I have added the goal to the cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin and saved the change. But the problem is getting the below error in the pom file :
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com.github.temyers:cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin:1.0.1:generateRunners (execution: generateRunners, phase: validate)

Comment: please checkout the sample pom.xml - https://github.com/llatinov/selenium-samples-java/blob/master/cucumber-parallel/pom.xml
you will know it works successfully when you have automatically generated java files at target/generated-test-sources/cucumber after a mvn clean test

Comment: After a mvn clean test, in target/generated-test-sources/cucumber,a file called Parallel01IT.java is created, which means the cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin works fine. Then getting this in the command line:   
2 Scenarios (2 undefined)
9 Steps (9 undefined)

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the glue code path or the configured feature file path. Google the exception or error message

Comment: patrick, I have added the above 2 plugins as you mentioned .Given the pkg name of the Stepdefinition as : <glue>stepDefinition</glue>
Then mvn test. Getting this error :
Running Parallel01IT
<< FAILURE! -in Parallel01IT
initializationError(Parallel01IT)  Time elapsed: 0.011 sec  <<< ERROR!
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: 
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 12
I should see {string} in {string} ^Caused by:java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: 
Tests in error: 
  Parallel01IT.initializationError » Cucumber java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxExcep...

Comment: Did you test even run in non-parallelized mode? Maybe you need to escape some characters as cucumber works with regex a { or similiar characters can be a problem if they are not escaped. look at https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/1307

Comment: yes. this code worked well in non-parallelized mode.
and getting this error when mvn clean test: 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.temyers:cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin:2
.1.0:generateRunners (generateRunners) on project DemoEurasia: Execution generat
eRunners of goal com.github.temyers:cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin:2.1.0:generateR
unners failed: Parser errors:
[ERROR] (17:3): inconsistent cell count within the table

Comment: have a look at the generated runner class and your origin runner and compare them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180864/discussion-between-milu-and-patrick-holzer).